# Is it important to set some sort of timer to avoid detection when web scraping?

Tags: web-scraping

I've set up a program in an attempt to do some scraping of a real estate site in order to get some statistical data about the market.

My program will probably call the web site about 150 times. And I want to do this once per day. I imagine the web is big enough, they will possibly get about 10,000 - 20,000 hits per day (estimate).

But if I sent these all together, would they think that they're putting flooded with requests? would they notice that I'm web scraping and block my IP?

If so, is it important to set a timer in? At the moment, I've put a timer that waits 3 to 5 seconds before each call, I'm just calling if that's necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Niklas. However, if you need the data 'faster' I would go with a timeout of 60 (up to 120) seconds. That is good for most of the servers today with the traffic size that you describe.
Also, to be on the good side of things, please make sure you are following the robots.txt definition and see if there is some limit there (in terms of timeouts and routes).

Comment: Web site owners use the /robots.txt file to give instructions about their site to web robots; this is called The Robots Exclusion Protocol. You can read more: http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: Thanks, it turns out that the robots.txt file doesn't have any instruction about delay. I'll probably just set it like you say to about 60 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

If they would be on the lookout for scrapers, it would most definitely stand out. With 10000-20000 hits per day, it would average to about one hit per 4 to 9 seconds. You'd be pushing ~2 hits in-between every real request, and with such short intervals, it wouldn't be difficult to filter out your requests.

A lot safer and polite thing to do would be to set the scraping to be done through the whole 24 hours, so putting the interval up to ~10 minutes. It won't bring them significant load differences (not that 150 requests should do anyway), and it would make it significantly harder to pin point as the requests become far more spread.